# how to break unordered list of links with image or color with css

Tags: css, html

what am trying to do is split/break each element in the unordered list with a white image so it looks like this :

[image]

I have the white image, but how I supposed to do that with CSS?

Comment: `border-left`/`border-right`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a `border-right` to your `li` elements, and use the `:last-child` selector to remove it for the last element (to avoid having a white border to the right of the last one, since there's no other list element after).

```
li{
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}

li:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h8z1gcLc/

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `:after` :pseudo-element to all `li`s but the last one by using `:not(:last-child)`.

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}
.nav-container {
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #FFFFF6;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #FFFFF6;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #423930, #A09B95);
  z-index: -1;
}
.nav li:not(:last-child) .menu-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px #FFFFF6;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item">Home</a></li
    ><li><a id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item">Register</a></li
    ><li><a id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item">Download</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```